# Copy a range of data from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, transfer

Im working with MySQL Events to select automatically a range of data from a Data Base in MySQL and I need to insert this data in other Server running SQL Server.

Do you know if it is possible?, How can I connect MySQL to SQL Server using tcp/ip or something like that to insert my data?

Comment: Export as a csv from mysql. sftp, ftp, rsync, email, carrier pigeon your data to somewhere where sql server can see it, and import. You can use MysqL Events to do the export and an SSIS package for the import.

Comment: You've reason, thanks.